# How to automatically update a deployed Node JS Electron program

Tags: node.js, auto-update, electron

I think the title should be quite self-explanatory. I am developing a Node JS app using Atom Electron. What I would need is a way to deploy my application in a cross-platform way (Mac OS X, Windows and Linux), while making it capable of automatically updating itself, without having to ask for administration privileges.

Here is what I would like to happen:

- The application gets installed by my users, possibly via an easy-to-use installer.
- I keep developing my app, adding new features, and so on.
- At some point, I release a new version of my code, I pack it somehow and upload it somewhere.
- All the clients that are currently online, or whenever a client gets back online, they download the new version, install it, and restart automatically, without having to ask for administration privileges.

As far as I know, there are apps that are capable of doing such a thing. For example, Google Chrome automatically installs updates without having to continuously ask for administrative privileges or, even worse, making its users download new installers all the time.

Is there an elegant and cross platform way to do such a thing? What would be the best solution for my problem?

If this is matters in any way, let me add that my project is completely open source, so I don't care about protecting my code in any way from being read.

Comment: it's not available on all platforms yet. https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1479
you may want to use Squirrel for mac like here https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1479
and yes, that will require root privileges if you want to have the app auto updated in the /Applications folder.
Probably the same stuff on windows. And on *nix based system it will depend on your installation. 
The possible solution is to write a temporary folder loader container, and ship it as a main app at first place.